# Can EL 2.2 capable JSF web applications be deployed to shared Tomcat 6 hosting environment?

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat6, el

I know that by replacing the `el-api.jar` in the lib folder of the Tomcat 6 directory with an EL 2.2 capable version that it is possible to utilize the power of EL 2.2 in Tomcat 6.  See the following questions:

- http://code2inspire.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/how-to-enable-el-2-2-on-tomcat-6/
- http://www.javaplex.com/blog/for-jsf-2-how-to-enable-el-2-2-on-tomcat-6/

I have an app that I need to deploy for a public facing site and I want to do it as cheaply as possible.  The best bargain for me would be to go with a Shared Tomcat hosting provider where you share a Tomcat instance with others, however the one I talked to doesn't offer Tomcat 7 environments.

It would be a lot more expensive and time consuming for me to setup a VPS to do this, so I was wondering if there is anyway I can swing this on Tomcat 6 without the ability to modify the lib directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JBoss EL instead. It is EL 2.1 based, but offers the [same enhancements](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest-2/reference/en-US/html/elenhancements.html) as done in EL 2.2. Drop [jboss-el.jar](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` and add the following to the `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

No need to modify Tomcat's `/lib`. You only need to ensure that you're using Facelets instead of JSP.

Comment: You sir are a gentlemen and a scholar, that worked perfectly!  Thank you!